# Django project structure / importing python views (beginner)

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.4 and i've been largely following the free online Django Book up to now, my folder structure looks like this:

```
TestWebsite/
        TestApp/
                __init.py
                admin.py
                models.py
                views.py
        TestWebsite/
                Webpage_Templates/
                        homepage.html
                __init__.py
                settings.py
                urls.py
                views.py
        manage.py
```

So far i've just been rendering views in the TestWebsite sub directory and so haven't had any path issues.

Now what i'd like to be able to do (and correct me if this is not how app integration should work), is:

- use the line `return render_to_response("homepage.html", {})` in
  *TestApp/views.py*
- then i'd need to import *TestApp/views.py* into *TestWebsite/urls.py* so
  that i can then add that to the urlpatterns. ( I assume i'd also have a problem with having two imports with the same name- views?)

I thought about using `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` like i've done in settings.py you but i still don't know how to handle the going up and down the directory structure. Plus it's not really a path i need anyway but a python import statement(i think) and i suppose those aren't really the same kettle of fish are they? You can tell i'm new to this. Would really appreciate some solid guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out/remembered that because the template directory is set in the settings file i didn't have to worry about the first bullet point, any app views i make can return pages in my Webpage_Templates folder without any difference in implementation.

As for the second bullet point, to prevent the same-name problem in urls.py i changed `import views` to:

```
from views import * #Now instead of views.ShowTime i just use ShowTime
```

and to access my apps views i just added,

```
from TestApp.views import *
```

much simpler than i'd thought it would be.

Answering my question because i know alot of the guides are for django version pre 1.4, where the default folder structure was a little different and other 1.4 beginners might stumble across this question wondering the same thing.

However if anyone want to expand on my solution by explaining it a bit more do go ahead and submit an answer!

Comment: Glad you've managed to solve your problem. Often, you don't actually need to include the views from your app in the main site `urls.py`. Instead, you _include_ the urls from your app. This is explained in the [decoupling the URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#decoupling-the-urlconfs) section of the tutorial. It's worth working through the complete tutorial if you haven't already. Unlike a lot of the guides, it is kept up to date, so there's less confusion when it comes to folder structures etc.